# Trying to apply choropleth on Indian map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to apply a choropleth on the Indian map Chart. But not able to achieve the result - [My demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2eLwxweLJhuUgTuOS4x?p=preview)

```
      var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
          .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(json, function (d) { return json.total; })])
          .range(colors);
```

I can sense that the above and below codes are the cause but am unable resolve it.

```
            india.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(json.total); });
```

the colors ref where taken from [bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084)

Comment: I would have put images instead of links to external websites which people generally frown upon trying, and eventually fiddles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the issues explained in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47475137/5768908), your color scale is wrong. Right now it returns this array as the domain:

```
[0, 8, 9765]
```

Which is probably not what you want.

Here is a different scale, dividing the domain in equal intervals from 0 to the maximum `total`:

```
var maxTotal = d3.max(json.features, function(d) {
    return d.total
});

var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain(d3.range(buckets).map(function(d) {
        return (d / buckets) * maxTotal
    }))
    .range(colors);
```

Now, this is the domain:

```
[0, 1085, 2170, 3255, 4340, 5425, 6510, 7595, 8680]
```

And here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CWn1vKbzDLq1YDAu9oD7?p=preview

Comment: hey, i tried to add legend to the chart and i find something wrong with the range. The gap between 0 and 1085 is too much that the first color that's supposed to be there is getting hidden with "y=0" & "height=0".

Refer updated plunker - [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2eLwxweLJhuUgTuOS4x?p=preview)

Comment: What you're asking is not clear... I suggest you post this as a new question, with the relevant details.

Comment: nevermind, i got few errors while adding legend for the map. Now got it [Updated Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1a8a5aaHJR5M20gaKfva?p=preview).
Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: No worries... feel free to post a new question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing the data to the quantile scale correctly.  And then you try to set the colors on your `india` variable (which is the svg) and not the paths:

```
  // pass json.features to d3.max, convert total to number
  var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(json.features, function (d) { return +d.total; })])
        .range(colors);

  ...

  // continue chaining off path creation
  // pass total to colorScale and convert to number
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
      return colorScale(+d.total);
  });
```

---

Running code updated [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mPWxSDuPtznf2wWbJY6t?p=preview).